# Can we perform reverse look up in Spring with EL Expressions

Tags: spring

Can we perform reverse look up in Spring with EL Expressions:
I have a util map in Spring with key - value pairs.
I want to find they key by value using spring el expression...
is that possible...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can iterate over map and they check if value is equal to the data you are looking for.If yes, return key.

```
//Java
Map<String, String> countryCapitalList = new HashMap<String, String>();
countryCapitalList.put("United States", "Washington DC");
countryCapitalList.put("India", "Delhi");
countryCapitalList.put("Germany", "Berlin");
countryCapitalList.put("France", "Paris");
countryCapitalList.put("Italy", "Rome");

request.setAttribute("capitalList", countryCapitalList);
```

//JSP

```
<c:forEach var="country" items="${capitalList}">
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test=${country.key == 'India'}
    Country: ${country.key}  - Capital: ${country.value}
    </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Here you can use

Comment: Not iterating through map... let me know, if we can do, any thing  with help of Spring EL expressions.